# How do I concatenate a certain amount of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, concatenation

I'm creating a program that reads lines from different text files and adds those lines into one array for each file. At one moment I then need to concatenate all of these arrays and then select a random item from it. This is the code I've tried so far, unfortunately it doesn't fill the array correctly :

```
private static String[] concat(ArrayList<String[]> arrays)
{
    int length = 0;

    for (String[] array : arrays)
        length += array.length;

    String[] first = arrays.get(0);
    String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, length);

    for (int i = 1; i < arrays.size(); i++)
    {
        String[] array = arrays.get(i);
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, arrays.get(i - 1).length, array.length);
    }

    return result;
}
```

I think I'm messing up the System.arraycopy parameters, but I'm not sure. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Where are you reading the files?

Comment: I'm actually reading the files just before concatenating all of the arrays.

Comment: `fileList.stream().flatMap(Files::lines)` or similar will give you a concatentated stream of lines from all the files. Note to select randomly you’ll either need to read the whole lot into memory or read the whole lot twice (to count the lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, problem is in `destPos` param, try so:

```
private static String[] concat(List<String[]> arrays) {
    int length = 0;

    for (String[] array : arrays)
        length += array.length;

    String[] first = arrays.get(0);
    String[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, length);

    int index = first.length;

    for (int i = 1; i < arrays.size(); i++) {
        String[] array = arrays.get(i);
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, result, index, array.length);
        index += array.length;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a stream approach instead of doing the coping and calculating the array lengths. Something like:

```
private static String[] concat(ArrayList<String[]> arrays){
    return arrays.stream().flatMap(Arrays::stream).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

Comment: The Stream API didn't work for me sadly, it would throw me an ArrayStoreException :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be useful, but I this reminded me of a program I had previously written as an example that uses a methods that takes two arrays and combines them to one. Sounds similar to what you're looking. If this works for you, just then generate a random number based on the length and reference that index.

```
public static String[] combineArrays(String[] a1, String[] a2) 
{
    // Get the size of each array
    int length1 = a1.length;
    int length2 = a2.length;
    int size = length1 + length2;
    
    String[] combinedArray = new String[size];
    
    // Load the first array into the combined array starting from the end
    // of the first 
    // Start at length of the first array and end at the total size
    for(int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        combinedArray[i] = a1[i];
    }
    
    // Keeps track of where we are in a2 
    int current = 0;
    // Load second array into combined array
    for (int j = length1; j < size; j++) {
        combinedArray[j] = a2[current];
        current++;
    }
    
    return combinedArray;
}
```

Comment: It would've been useful if I was working with only 2 arrays, but unfortunately I have tons of files and I can't just modify my code each time I create a new file. But thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Understandable! What about calling the method from within a loop for as many arrays as you need to combine? I.e. for 3 it would look like this:

    `String[] fruits = {"peach", "kiwi", "banana", "strawberry", "pear"};
        String[] vegetables = {"carrot", "sprout", "parsnip", "broccoli"};
        String[] candy = {"chocolate", "swedish fish", "sour patch kids"};
        
        String[] combined = combineArrays(fruits, vegetables);
        combined = combineArrays(combined, candy);
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combined));`

Comment: Not really because I would still have to modify my code for the amount of for loops. I want my code to be dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static String[] concat(List<String[]> arrays) {
    int length = 0;

    for (String[] array : arrays)
        length += array.length;

    String[] result = new String[length];
    int offs = 0;

    for (String[] arr : arrays) {
        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, result, offs, arr.length);
        offs += arr.length;
    }

    return result;
}
```